# error: The argument type 'void Function()?' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'void Function(String?)?'

Tags: flutter, dart

the error is simple i dont know how to solve the problem please help

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class CheetahInput extends StatelessWidget {
  final String? labelText;
  final VoidCallback? onSaved;

  CheetahInput({@required this.labelText, @required this.onSaved});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return TextFormField(
      decoration: InputDecoration(
        fillColor: Colors.white,
        filled: true,
        labelText: labelText,
        border: OutlineInputBorder(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(16),
        ),
        floatingLabelBehavior: FloatingLabelBehavior.never,
      ),
      initialValue: '',
      validator: (String? value) {
        return value!.isEmpty ? '$labelText is required' : null;
      },
      onSaved: onSaved,
    );
  }
}
```

i tried to specify the type with angular brackets but it didnt  work
i appreciate your help inadvance.

Comment: onSaved is not VoidCallback ! You should provide customCallback or function with a parameter of String?

Comment: could you please provide the code ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace

`final VoidCallback? onSaved;`

with

`final FormFieldSetter<String>? onSaved;`

Answer (score 2):

Replace

```
final VoidCallback? onSaved;
```

with

```
final Function(String)? onSaved;
```